# Ideal MySQL Configuration on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, storage

I am looking to run MySQL/MariaDB in Azure to host several databases totalling around 100GB, I'd like to at least have 50GB room to grow, and ideally have this on SSD.

It appears that Microsoft offers a "MySQL application preview", however I'm concerned about putting production work on a "preview" system.

That being said, the next best option appears to be spinning up an Ubuntu 16.04 VM with sufficient disk size, which would run between $850 and $1200 a *month*, which feels a bit excessive.

I've also seen that there may be a way to attach a disk that consumes my storage accounts "blob" that I can attach, perhaps, to a cheaper VM.

How are people currently implementing this configuration? I feel I am completely off track buying something that expensive to use as a DB server.

Comment: The most expensive part of an Azure VM will be the compute power required.  Which VM sizes are you looking at?

Comment: Really, any of the offerings with SSD and 150GB+ of storage. I don't have a good way to estimate my needed "compute units", so (while relevant) I'm treating that as irrelevant at the moment.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering how you arrived at 850 a month.  What VM size did you pick.  Is your workload cpu or memory intensive?

Comment: I'm guessing that he was looking at the temporary disk sizes for the VMs to determine which size to pick. @RobertLerner, you will attach a data disk of a custom size (up to 4TB) separately from the disk size you see on the instance size pages.  That disk size is a temporary disk for non-permanent storage.  Depending on the load, you could probably use an A2 or A2M VM with a 150GB SSD data disk.

Comment: CtrlDot, So far DS5_V2 looks to be the cheapest option, with 112GB of storage. @Mitch, I don't see those sizes under "Ubuntu Server 16.04", I'm not sure what the A2 or A2M mean, tbh. So the temporary disk size is for the OS? Or no? Just not sure the process of attaching a disk later or if I just provision that seperately.

Comment: The temporary disk is a separate disk from your OS and data disks.  It's storage that's local to the VM, so it's fast, but it's not permanent in any way.  It's generally used for page/swap files and any temporary data.  You can see the A-size VMs at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes-general#av2-series.  When building the VM, make sure you click "View All" on the top right to see the A sizes.  They aren't shown by default.  Also, the A sizes don't support SSD storage.  If you want SSD, I'd start with DS1 or DS2 depending on needs.

Comment: Separate comment since I hit the limit.  What you need to do is build the VM based on the core and RAM count you're looking for - ignore the disk size listed completely.  Your OS disk will be 32GB (I believe) by default.  Then, after it's built, there's a Disks page within the VM settings in the portal that will let you add a data disk of any size, up to 4TB.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm we have thousands of customers using our Preview service for MySQL for production purposes today.  Geekwire.com is just one of them.  From a support perspective, we treat it no different today than what we'll do when we reach General Availability.

As for how many Compute Units you need, you can roughly equate 100 Compute Units to 1 core - however don't compare that to how many cores you'd need for an IaaS VM implementation.  Cores for a PaaS service are dedicated to the MySQL Server only - not the host OS.  However, if you find that your current Compute Units aren't enough, you can scale up (or down) for that matter without having to provision a new instance.  It happens on the fly with about 20-30s of downtime.

Hope this helps!
Jason - Azure Database for MySQL team @ Microsoft

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply. I've tried the preview product and find that it won't work for me. I do not have control over many of the settings, I had issues importing a table (kept getting return code "1"), and finally, I strongly dislike the lowercasing of the table/db names. I realize it must be Windows-backed, but it doesn't work for our needs.

Comment: Would love to further understand what settings you'd like access to and specifically why.  The reason we don't expose all settings as some can impact the performance guarantee of the server which we want to be careful of.  However we're actively taking feedback on this and will likely open more up - but need feedback to do so.